# How do I set my Eclipse to compile for Android 2.3

Tags: android

This is probably very basic but I have failed to find information on how to do this. On iOS I have a base SDK and a target SDK so I can use the latest features from the base SDK (of course check if they are available first) and at the same time make my app run on devices with the target SDK. How can I do the same thing with Android in Eclipse, how can I compile with Android 4.1 and at the same time make my app run on (deploy to) Android 2.3?

Im not asking about checking which version I am running at run time, but how do I configure Eclipse correctly.

Thank you

Søren

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by reading [backward compability](http://developer.android.com/training/search/backward-compat.html) on Android developer site. You are probably looking for "Set Minimum and Target API levels".

Comment: Hm yes I had read that and I was 100% sure I had tested it and my app would not deploy to my 2.3 emulator, but I tested again and now it will. Ok sorry about that, it seems I successfully confused my self.

Answer (score 0):

On your Androidmanifest.xml check for the uses-sdk tag

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
```

version 8 is Android 2.2 up to 16 for 4.1/4.1.1

from [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html)